# Angular/IONIC sum ng-model

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm creating something very simple, which would calculate the value of multiple radio buttons as you would to calculate?Already defined a ng-model, and a value for each radio, which are on separate screens, I would like to show the result in the last screen.

```
<ion-view title="Primeira Pergunta">
<ion-content padding="'true'" class="has-header">
    <h3>Escolha a quantidade de equipamento</h3>
    <form class="list">
        <ion-radio ng-model="item.value" ng-value="1000">até 10</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio ng-model="item.value" ng-value="2000">até 50</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio ng-model="item.value" ng-value="6000">até 100</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio ng-model="item.value" ng-value="5000">Franquias</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio ng-model="item.value" ng-value="9000">Corporate</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio ng-model="item.value" ng-value="300000">Cobertura Nacional</ion-radio>
    </form>
    <div class="spacer" style="width: 300px; height: 15px;"></div>
    <a menu-close="" href="#/page3" class="button button-assertive button-block ">Próximo</a>
</ion-content>
```

```
<ion-view title="Segunda Pergunta">
<ion-content padding="'true'" class="has-header">
    <h4>Você já o flagrou lhe observando enquanto você não estava olhando?</h4>
    <form class="list"></form>
    <form class="list">
        <ion-radio ng-model="item.value" ng-value="30">Não</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio ng-model="item.value" ng-value="70">Sim, 1 vez!</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio ng-model="item.value" ng-value="100">Sim, Mais de 1 vez!</ion-radio>
    </form>
    <div class="spacer" style="width: 300px; height: 142px;"></div>
    <a menu-close="" href="#/page4" class="button button-assertive button-block ">Próximo</a>
</ion-content>
```

The result of the calculation would come out here:

```
<ion-view title="Resultado">
<ion-content padding="'true'" class="has-header">
    <img src="img/AUQTMPyoQBGBfnD5HDC7_logo-portal-wp-como-conquistar-um-homem.png" width="100%" height="auto" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
    <h2>Você Fez:</h2>
    <div>{{item.value}}</div>
    <a href="https://e-editora.leadpages.co/leadbox/1457a340bf72a2%3A944764f46/5668783041544192/" target="_blank" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-decoration: none; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px; display: inline-block; max-width: 300px; border-radius: 5px; background: rgb(255, 206, 10);">Clique Aqui e veja uma analise personalizada da sua nota</a>
</ion-content>
```

I'm no expert, just a job for college, how would this calculation with the js?

Comment: Did you write any JS at all?

Comment: I think that would create a js to make this calculation right?

Comment: The calculation would be only for what is selected.

Comment: The "ion-view" are on separate controllers or the same?

Comment: They are all on separate controllers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each question must have its different ng-model. After you can sum ng-model this way:

```
<h2>Você Fez:</h2>
<div>{{value1 + value2}}</div>
```

or use function

```
<h2>Você Fez:</h2>
<div>{{ getTotal() }}</div>

$scope.getTotal = function(){    
   $scope.value1 + $scope.value2;     
   return ...
```

Now, if your ion-view are on separate controllers, you must share $scope between controllers with AngularJs or you need re-think you problem.

See here: http://gonzalo123.com/2014/09/08/sharing-scope-between-controllers-with-angularjs/

Comment: Thanks for the help, I now believe I can do. Thank you.